# How do ranges::views achieve O(1) complexity?

Tags: c++, complexity-theory, c++20, range-v3, std-ranges

On the recently introduced to C++20 Ranges, I know that `views` achieve composability by using view adaptors. I also know that **views don't own their elements** and that their nature is lazy, that is to say they only do the actual computation when it's needed.

How do views achieve `O(1)` complexity on move, copy and assign operations though? The probable answer that comes to me is, views being just *descriptions* of "to be computed" operations, they just refer to the data and their transformations.

That, though, sounds like views are just taking on the job of expressing our coding sequences and only when passed to some eager thing (e.g. an algorithm) do they manifest all the computational load in this particular, single call.

*Follow up question*: I can understand how one would achieve a `O(1)` copy, in the essence of referring to the copiable object (although I don't know if that's what `ranges::views` do). But I cannot understand how this will work in assignment operations. Again, a probable answer would be, since all these happen in compile time, then again just "*describing*" the assignment is an `O(1)` operation. But mutating an `std::vector<int>` that's viewed by a view, is a runtime operation instead (great [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62609758/updating-results-during-runtime-with-ranges)). Is this still an `O(1)` operation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You recognize that views don't own the elements that they reference or manipulate. But you don't seem to understand that this is *why* these operations are O(1).

If you have this:

```
vector<int> v = {...};
auto *vptr = &v;

auto *vptr2 = vptr;
vptr = vptr2;
```

What is the complexity of the initialization of `vref2` relative to `v.size()`? What is the complexity of the assignment to `vptr` relative to `v.size()`?

They're both O(1) because they're *just copying pointers*.

`vptr` points to `v`; it doesn't own it. Being a pointer is *how* it doesn't own `v`. It is also how copying a pointer is an O(1) operation: because the size of the pointer doesn't care about the size of the data it points to.

The same goes for views. View types store iterators/sentinels for the underlying range. Pointers are a kind of iterator, but iterators work a lot like pointers in that they point into a sequence of values rather than *being* the sequence itself. A range is defined by a starting iterator and a value which represents the end of that range (sometimes another iterator, other times a general object that can be tested against an iterator).

Iterator types don't know or care about how many elements are in the sequence. The iterator concept models a position in a sequence; conceptually, it has no idea what the end point is.

So copying an iterator is (usually) O(1) relative to the size of the range they point to. The same is true of movement and copy/move assignment.

Comment: As described in my follow up question that's exactly the answer I expected. Thank you for that! What happens when views actually describe computations that are to be made on their reffered data though? Say `views::transform` for exapmle. How do pointers manage to do the job then?

Comment: @gonidelis: It stores the function to call. And whatever that function is, its copy/move operation has no relation to the size of the range.

Comment: "iterators cannot know how big the range is" - they can. In some cases, they have to. `filter_view::iterator` has to know where the end is to do `++` correctly, for instance.

Comment: @Barry You are talking about `counter_iterator`s?